# SVN repository creation question

Tags: svn, repository

I am checking out the current version of a design with the current command:

```
 svn checkout svn+ssh://test@example.com/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design1 .
```

That works fine, and I made some substantial changes to the implemetation so
that I would like hold a copy of this milestone in the SVN. In other words,
I would like to check in the current version into an own directory, ie "design2":

In doing so, I would like to be able to checkout this version similar as above

```
 svn checkout svn+ssh://test@example.com/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design2 .
```

I have never create a new directory in the SVN, so I am wondering if I have to create
a subrepository to be able to check out design2 as follows:

```
 su - svn
 mkdir svn+ssh://test@example.com/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design2
 svnadmin create svn+ssh://test@example.com/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design2
```

Is there a problem when I create this from files that I checked out earlier? I know how to deal with SVN after this step, but I never created a new directory/repository
for a new implementation so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you want to make a new branch, i.e. you want `design1` and `design2` to live side by side so that they can diverge.

Don't create a new repository with `svnadmin`. Instead, do this:

```
    cd design1
    svn status # make sure everything is ready as if for a normal commit
    svn copy . svn+ssh://server.ac.uk/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design2 -m "creating new branch for design 2"
```

Now delete your working copy (it is still pointing at design1 and contains pending changes , even though they have been committed to design2 -- yes, it's confusing, best to just delete it). Create a new checkout for design2 so you can continue making changes and committing:

```
   cd ..
   rm -rf design1
   svn co svn+ssh://server.ac.uk/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design2
   cd design2
```

This is a somewhat complicated way to commit changes to a new branch. Normally you would first create a branch (`svn copy url1 url2`), check out the branch in a separate working copy, and *then* make changes. That isn't possible in this case because you have already made changes intended for a new branch in the first working copy.

Note that the layout in your repository does not follow the
[recommended repository layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout). This doesn't have to be a problem, but I would recommend you follow the conventions for future projects.

Comment: When I enter svn status I get the following output: svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy. Plus when I say "svn co svn+ssh://server.ac.uk/mainrepository/trunk/projects/design2" I am told that svn: Directory '/home/projects/revision/.svn'containing working copy admin area is missing. No idea what this is supposed to mean...

Comment: @Heinz: if the design1 folder was created by a `svn checkout` command, then you should not get those errors. I can only assume that it was not, and that you are still a bit confused about basic SVN concepts. Maybe it is best if you first read through the first two chapters of the SVN book before trying to tackle more advanced topics such as branching: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your layout is a little confusing.  You have a repository, called main repo - which has branches tags and trunk under it.  This is very very standard.  However it looks like there are multiple projects under the the trunk? do they in turn have branches, tags and trunk directories under them?  Are they built/tagged and released together or independently?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it should be made a separate [branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html). You don't want people working on `project1` to have to check out all the code for `project2` as well (which they will do if they checkout at the trunk level).

It looks like you might be keeping all of your projects in one repository, which is not something I would do. At that point you are subverting some of the usefulness of revision control.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you have your project structured in branches, tags and trunk (or something similar) you can create a sub-project or a sub-directory for your edit, and then merge it with the trunk (or the working project)

```
svn copy /projectRoot/trunk /projectRoot/branches/edit1
```

Which will intelligently copy files, so when you can only download edits, and not the whole project again...